# Sharing only the templates without giving access to source code

Tags: django, templates

I'd like to share the templates of the website I've done with a graphist. My problem is that *I dont want him to access the Python code at all*.

It's easy to share a folder and give access to it through sftp.

I was wondering if it were possible given a right tag, to access my Python code. I know for example that with Php/Smarty or with Php/Twig, you can execute Php code, which means you can read whatever you want, including all the source files (I've done it to test). So sharing Php templates files and thinking "my source code is safe" is a mistake.

I'm a beginner with Django, and I'm wondering if there's a way to access the source files through Django template system / or not?

Comment: You might want to test `{% include "../../models.py" %}` or some such. It shouldn't work, but I've never tried.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich FYI it's working, but all files includes only classes, nothing else, so even though it's executed, they are only declarations, so nothing is happening. The more I practice, the more I'm dazzled with Django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django's template system is specifically written with this use case in mind; the original developers, at the Lawrence Journal-World newspaper in Kansas, wanted to be able to give the templates to designers to produce, while working on the Python code themselves.

There is no way to access arbitrary Python code from a Django template.